# How to create a date from a String by using createFromDate from a broken format

Tags: php, datetime

I try to parse a string into a Date by using [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to avoid several local problems which could occur if I use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

The string is in this: "2016-01-14 00:16:18 UTC+1"

So I'm looking for a format-string which maps the given date. So far I have tryed the following formats, but they don't work.

```
$str = '2016-01-14 00:16:18 UTC+1';

$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s e', $str);
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s eO', $str);
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s eP', $str);
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s T', $str);
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s TO', $str);
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s TP', $str);
```

So the question is, how can I seperate the time-zone from the difference of this time-zone or if it is impossible. Then I need a way how to handle it else.

Comment: The string isn't strictly valid - it should be `2016-01-14 00:16:18 UTC+0100` to match `Y-m-d H:i:s eO`

Comment: @CD001_27 I know, the problem is that the strings comes from third-party so I have to parse that ugly thing.

Comment: You could probably map that `UTC+1` part to a given timezone string, strip it from the `$str` and use something like `$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $str, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));`

Comment: @CD001 That looks basically like a nice Idea, but it is not very flexible. So I decided to simply reformat the String and fix it before I parse the date. That should work in most cases even if it is very ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, that date format is odd.

Here is a very simple fix using `str_replace()`,

which cuts out "UTC", leaving "+1" - and that should be recognized by "e" or "P".

**Source**

```
<?php

$str = '2016-01-14 00:16:18 UTC+1';

$str = str_replace('UTC', '', $str); // fix odd date string

$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s P';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $str);

var_dump($date);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Result**

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2016-01-14 00:16:18.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 1
  public 'timezone' => string '+01:00' (length=6)

2016-01-14 00:16:18
```

Comment: That's basically what I did after some more research. It seems to be the best solution for this odd format.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is basically the part of the string `UTC+1` ... however, that's not too far off the valid TimeZone format of `Etc/GMT+1` so it should be possible to remap it.

The quick and easy way to do this is just to replace 'UTC' with 'GMT':

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s e', str_replace('UTC', 'GMT', $str));
```

The string then becomes **2016-01-14 00:16:18 GMT+1** which *is* valid and you get a working `DateTime` object. You can test this with:

```
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e')
// prints '2016-01-14 00:16:18 +01:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="date">
```

Users are forced to the correct format. However it is mm-dd-yyyy. In Europe we prefer day first.